# Bond price under Poissonian model of interest rate

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, bond, poisson

Working through an exercise in interest rate modelling and I have the following  setup:
$r_t = r_0 + \delta N_t$ where $\delta > 0$ and $\lambda > 0$ is the intensity of the Poisson pricess $N_t$. I want to calculate the bond price at time $0$, which is given by the formula
$$
B(0,T) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}^*}\left( e^{-\int_0^T r_u \,du}\right) = e^{-r_0T}\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}^*}\left( e^{-\delta \int_0^T N_u\,du}\right).
$$
where $\mathbb{P}^*$ is the risk-neutral probability measure. I haven't been dealing with Poisson processes lately and am not sure if there is a simple transformation or use of MGFs to get the second integral/expectation using properties of the Poisson process. I have tried to find some resources online but to no avail! Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Stochastic Fubini theorem might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$Y_t = \int_0^t N_u du$$

where $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ figures a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.

Using the stochastic Fubini theorem we have that:
\begin{align}
Y_T &= \int_0^T N_t dt \\
&= \int_0^T \int_0^t dN_u dt \\
&\color{lightgray}{= \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbf{1}\{u \in [0,t]\} dN_u\ dt} \\
&\color{lightgray}{= \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbf{1}\{u \in [0,t]\} dt\ dN_u} \\
&\color{lightgray}{= \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbf{1}\{t \in [u,T]\} dt dN_u} \\
&= \int_0^T \int_u^T dt dN_u \\
&= \int_0^T (T-u) dN_u \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} (T-T_i) \tag{0}
\end{align}
where $T_i$ figures the $i^{th}$ Poisson process jump time, which is Gamma distributed with integer parameter $i$ (also known as Erlang distribution see [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf) Proposition 15.2 for instance). The jump times $T_i$ are therefore not unconditionally i.i.d. and $Y_t$ cannot be seen as a usual compound Poisson process.

But, conditioning helps! Indeed, conditionally on the number of jumps $N_T = n$ one can show that the $n$ jump times $\{T_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are actually independently and identically distributed uniformly over $[0,T]$ (see reference [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf) top of page 443), that is
\begin{align}
T_i\ \vert\ N_T=n \ \ &\sim\ \ T U_i\\
\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n  \ &\sim\ \ \mathcal{U}[0,1] \ \ \text{i.i.d.}
\end{align}

We then have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[e^{-\delta Y_T} \vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] &= \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \exp\left(-\delta \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} (T-T_i)\right) \right\vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] \tag{1} \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \exp\left(-\delta \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} (T-T_i)\right) \right\vert \mathcal{F}_T \right] \right\vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] \tag{2} \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \exp\left(-\delta T \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} (1-U_i) \right) \right\vert \mathcal{F}_T \right] \right\vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] \tag{3} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp\left(-\delta T \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tilde{U}_i \right) \right] \mathbb{P}^*\left( N_T = n \right) \tag{4}\\
&= e^{-\lambda T} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!} \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp\left(-\delta T \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tilde{U}_i \right) \right] \tag{5} \\
&= e^{-\lambda T} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left[   \exp\left(-\delta T \tilde{U}_i \right) \right] \tag{6} \\
&= e^{-\lambda T} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!} \left(\mathbb{E} \left[ \exp\left(-\delta T \tilde{U}_1 \right) \right]\right)^n \tag{7} \\
&= \exp(-\lambda T) \exp\left(\lambda T \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp\left(-\delta T \tilde{U}_1 \right) \right] \right) \tag{8} \\
&= \exp\left(\lambda T \left(\mathbb{E} \left[ \exp\left(-\delta T \tilde{U}_1 \right) \right] - 1 \right) \right)   \tag{9}
\end{align}
where $\tilde{U}_i = 1-U_i$ are also $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ i.i.d. by construction and we used:

1. Def. of $Y_T \vert \mathcal{F}_0 = \int_0^T N_u du = \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} (T-T_i)$ see $(0)$
2. Tower property of conditional expectation
3. Conditionally on $N_T$ the Poisson jump times are i.i.d. $\mathcal{U}[0,T]$
4. Expectation over $N_T \vert \mathcal{F}_0$
5. Def. of Poisson Process $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$
6. Properties of $\exp(.)$ + $\{\tilde{U}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ independent
7. $\{\tilde{U}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ identically distributed
8. Series expansion of $\exp(.)$
9. Properties of $\exp(.)$

Now all you need to do is compute $Z = \mathbb{E}[\exp\left(-\delta T U \right)]$  with $U \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$:

\begin{align}
Z &= \mathbb{E}[\exp\left(-\delta T U \right)] \\
&= \int_{0}^1 \exp\left(-\delta T u \right) \underbrace{p^*(u)}_{\mathbf{1}\{u \in [0,1]\}} du \\
&= \left[ \frac{\exp\left(-\delta T u \right)}{-\delta T} \right]_0^1 \\
&= \frac{1 - e^{-\delta T}}{\delta T}
\end{align}

You will then be able to write:
$$ e^{-r_0T}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}^*}\left[ e^{-\delta \int_0^T N_u\,du} \vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] = \exp\left(-r_0T + \lambda T\left(\frac{1 - e^{-\delta T}}{\delta T}-1\right)\right) $$

Comment: Wow thanks so much for that long type up! I suspected stochastic Fubini had to be used but wasn't sure of the details. Conditioning for Poisson (discrete) / Exponential (continuous) always seem to be a good approach for these type of things don't they. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome and yes indeed :) I am glad that it helped. I suspect there might be a less hand wavy way to do it though.

Comment: Just a quick one - the last expression does not need the expectation but all good apart from that. Cheers

Comment: @user89635 You are absolutely right, thanks for proofreading.